# How to merge multiple JSON arrays that are present in the same JSON file to single array

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am getting the below-shown example from the python script that I ran. I would like to merge all the arrays to a single array as shown in the output needed below.
Example:

```
[
  {
    "key": "65",
    "type": "Rug" 
  },
  {
    "key": "66",
    "type": "Rug" 
  }
][
  {
    "key": "52",
    "type": "A" 
  }
]
```

Needed Ouput:

```
[
  {
    "key": "65",
    "type": "Rug" 
  },
  {
    "key": "66",
    "type": "Rug" 
  },
  {
    "key": "52",
    "type": "A" 
  }

]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem description indicates you simply want to concatenate the arrays, which can easily be done using the "slurp" command-line option:

```
jq -s add
```

### Efficiency

If efficiency is an issue, which it might be if the number of input arrays is very large, then you could take advantage of the stream-oriented nature of the input:

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $in ([]; .+$in)'
```